# Выравнивание элементов

Tags: android

Стоит следующая задача. Есть 5 кнопок с фиксированной шириной каждая (могут различаться). Необходимо разместить их одной строкой с одинаковым зазором между ними (зависит от разрешения экрана). Можно, ли как то сверстать такое в xml, т.к. программно делать не хочется.

P.S.: Ширина кнопок меняться не должна. Надо менять именно зазор между ними.

Comment: Вставьте между кнопок view, которые будут служить распорками, и для них уже назначайте layout_weight. Разумеется, всё это должно быть внутри LinearLayout с orientation="horizontal".

Или же, второй вариант, обернуть каждую кнопку в RelativeLayout, для кнопок поставить layout_centerHorizontal="true", а для RelativeLayout - layout_weight="0.2". Всё это засовываем, опять-таки, в LinearLayout.

Comment: Об этом я думал, но как то это костыльно.

Comment: Боюсь, иначе никак, если именно XML-layout'ом решать задачу.

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно такое сделать с помощью свойства **LinearLayout**  - **weightSum**

Тебе необходимо создать **LinearLayout** c **weightSum = 5**, затем для каждого **child** указать **layout_weight = 1**.

Таким образом ширина **LinearLayout** разделится поровну на 5 частей и каждый **child** будет иметь ширину, равную одной пятой родительской ширины.

Comment: Или выставить для кнопок layout_weight="0.2" и тогда не понадобится менять weightSum.

Comment: да можно и так кстати

Comment: В том то и дело, что ширина кнопок меняться не должна, должны меняться зазоры между ними

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поместить их в LinearLayout с горизонтальной ориентацией и для каждой кнопки задать для каждой кнопки опступы(margins). 
[Здесь](http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/38-urok-7-layout-parametry-dlja-view-elementov.html) подробно написано.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ну во первых разве не нужно weightSum? а во вторых разве не приниятно в таком случае layout_width делать равным 0dp?

Comment: @rasmisha без weightSum отлично работает, layout_width = 0dp, кнопки пропадают, когда этого хочет редактор, он warning показывает!

Comment: @katso серьезно что-ли отлично? Даже интересно стало проверить, вечером дома посмотрю даже специально. И warning'ов у меня не было помнится